# Gradient descent math implementation explanation needed.

Tags: math, machine-learning, linear-algebra, linear-regression, logistic-regression

I know the solution but I don't understand how  the following equation was translated to code.

[image: Gradient Descent]

- Why the sum is missing?
- Why are we transposing the ((sigmoid(X *
  theta)-y) expression?

Solution

```
grad  = (1/m) * ((sigmoid(X * theta)-y)' * X);
```

Comment: Sum isn't missing.  The summation sign inside the left square bracket applies to all terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original line J(theta) represents the cost function for logistic regression.

The code that you showed, `grad = ...`, is the *gradient* of J(theta) with respect to the parameters; that is, `grad` is an implementation of d/dtheta J(theta). The derivative is important because that is used in gradient descent to move the parameters toward their optimal values (to minimize the cost J(theta)).

Below is the formula for the gradient, outlined in red, taken from the first [link](http://feature-space.com/2011/10/28/logistic-cost-function-derivative/) below. Note that J(theta) is the same as your formula above and h(x) represents the sigmoid function.

The total gradient over all training examples requires a summation over m. In your code for `grad` above, you are computing the gradient over one training example due to the omission of the summation; thus, your code is probably computing the gradient for [stochastic gradient descent](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-gradient-descent-and-stochastic-gradient-descent), not full gradient descent.

[image]

For more information, you can google for "logistic regression cost function derivative", which leads to these links:

1. This one in particular has everything you need: http://feature-space.com/2011/10/28/logistic-cost-function-derivative/
2. These are apparently some lecture notes from Andrew Ng's class on machine learning and logistic regression with gradient descent: http://www.holehouse.org/mlclass/06_Logistic_Regression.html
3. Explanation of how to compute the derivative step-by-step: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477207/derivative-of-cost-function-for-logistic-regression

Answer (score 1):

As it's been said, the mathematical expression you've posted is the cost function, whereas the code snippet you show is the gradient.

However, the summation is not missing. Let's break it down.

The gradient of the cost function with respect to the j-th parameter is
[image]

With `X * theta` you get a vector that contains the dot product of all your data points and your parameter vector.

With `sigmoid(X * theta)` you evaluate the sigmoid of each of those dot products.

With `X * theta)-y` you get a vector containing the differences between all your predictions and the actual labels.

With `sigmoid(X * theta)-y)' * X` you are transposing the vector of sigmoid evaluations and computing its dot product with each of the columns  of your data set (i.e. each of the x_j's for each data point).

Think about it for a second, and you'll see how that's exactly the summation in the expression, but evaluated for all the entries of your parameter vector, not just `j`.